# Linking a game database to a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

My friend has setting up a database for a Ragnarok Online server, and he wants me to code the relative website, which is going to use some of that data (and obviously, i'll have to add tables for the news system, website accounts, etc). Since i'm learning RoR i was going to do it that way.
I have a few "best practice" questions related to this :
Should I create a different database for the website, since it's going to have its particular data alongside the game data ? (i already have a few clues to link multiple databases with Rails, but that seems too much of a hassle for what it is).
If not, do i have to create Model/Controller for each of the tables composing the database, despite the fact that i'm not going to use 90% of it ? Or just the ones that i need ?

An example of this problem : the game database has its own "user" table, but i have to have another "user" table for the website, and do some Joins between those two. So, what's the best practice here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhm, best practice is not making your own user table. This will cause you much pain. Best practice? Use an API. Expose the game's database in some way to your website, and fetch that info with external requests in your web application.

The reason why making a second user table is a hassle:

> 1) You'll constantly have to update it, pulling data from the original
>   to keep it up-to-date.

And I mean furthermore, you're gonna have to create a CRON job or something pulling data from that original table to keep it up to date. Yuck. Also what if that CRON job makes a mistake? (It will)

> 2) It's almost inevitable that there will be inconsistencies if two
>   separate tables are maintained. Are you sure your web application is
>   really fail-proof?

**Update:**

What you're gonna need is essentially a second Rails application that acts as a REST API for that database. For a good idea of what REST is, I'd read through this to get you started: http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife

Once you have a good understanding of that, start making your app, and test if it's working by using tools like cURL to send requests to your API.

Once you have *that* done, I'd take a look into the Ruby [rest-client gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client) like Nobita mentioned. This is what you're going to use from your web application to request information from your API application.

Just let me note, I think this would be a terrible first Rails project, unless you're already really well versed in other web development tools, preferably MVC frameworks.

Comment: +1 Good answer, but what about explaining how to communicate with the potential API (like for example, using rest-client gem?

Comment: Ok thanks! And yeah, what do you mean by "use an API" ? Since i'm a rails newbie i didn't hear about that.

Comment: @Willy I'd like to tell you more, but you'd need to provide more information on the game's "database". What technology are you using for this game? What database are you using? I need more specifics.

Comment: Also, APIs really aren't specific to Rails. In fact, all types of software use APIs. I'd do a little Googling.

Comment: Well it's just a MySQL database, and it uses specific names and types for the game server to recognize, nothing too fancy. I guess I just have to add my infos in it, it's just that i will not be using a large amount of the tables (even on the user table, i will not be using eveything but i will have to have additionnal fields unrelated to the game) and that they're not following rails conventions, that's why i was asking for "best practice" for this kind of case.

Comment: What's the game server built with? Essentially you'll need this server -- or more likely, another web server, to handle receiving requests, fetching data, and then presenting it back to the requester. (That's your API in a nutshell.)